# UiTableView reloadData not calling cellForRowAtIndex

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, reloaddata

For some reason when I am trying to reload the data on a `UITableViewController` embedded in a ContainerView, it never calls the `numberOfRowsForIndex` or `cellForRowAtIndex`.

```
class SelectedDatesTableViewController: UITableViewController { 

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.preferredContentSize.height = CGFloat( SelectedDatesTimeAway.selectedDates.count * 44 )
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return SelectedDatesTimeAway.selectedDates.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("dateCell")! as UITableViewCell
        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateStyle = .ShortStyle
        dateFormatter.timeStyle = .NoStyle

        cell.textLabel?.text! = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(SelectedDatesTimeAway.selectedDates[indexPath.row])

        return cell
    }

    func reloadTable() {
        self.preferredContentSize.height = CGFloat( SelectedDatesTimeAway.selectedDates.count * 44 )
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that `self.tableView` isn't `nil`?

Comment: Negative to both, i get "<UITableView: 0x7fd369994000; frame = (0 20; 1366 1004); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7fd36b941df0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fd36b992ba0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {1366, 52}>" for print of the tableView and i get the correct number of items from count

Comment: Are the `dataSource` and `delegate` properties correctly set? Is the embedded controller's view properly inserted into a view hierarchy?

Comment: Yes they are. I checked them in storyboard and then I also just tried setting them explicitly

Comment: numberOfCells is getting called actually. Just not cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: Are you sure selectedDates isn't empty?

Comment: Yes it is not empty. I start with it being empty and then add data to it and then refresh the table view.

Comment: Put a breakpoint in the `numberOfRowsAtIndexPath` function. Make sure `selectedDates.count` isn't 0 when it's called as a result of `reloadData`.

Comment: It is not, I just checked it. It's returning the right amount of items.

Comment: Here's a small snippet for creation of your date formatter so you aren't creating one for every cell. `private lazy var dateFormatter: NSDateFormatter = {
        var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateStyle = .ShortStyle
        dateFormatter.timeStyle = .NoStyle
        
        return dateFormatter
    }()`

Comment: Set some different colours for the background of your tableview and cells to make sure that the tableview is actuall visible.

Comment: So the TableView is visible, but the cells are not being created.

Comment: How do you embed in the container view - in storyboard or in code?